# Emails received on Rackspace cloud

Tags: email, cloud, rackspace

I have a cloud slice on rackspace and the emails received there can only be seeing through terminal. In order to get a userfriendly interface from rackspace for a cost which is a bit prohibitive for my client, so I was wondering if there is a simple and userfriendly way so setup up a email interface on my slice, or any other good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go for roundcube: [this link](http://roundcube.net)

They have a really neat `UI`, very close to `GMail` with drag-and-drop support.